# Regular expression for the name

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to build a regex for a name with the following pattern, so
**John D.E.** would pass the regex test.
Basically what I want is:

1. N number of chars(a-zA-Z) goes first
2. Then there's exactly one space
3. Exactly one char(a-zA-Z)
4. Exactly one dot
5. Exactly one char(a-zA-Z)
6. Exactly one dot

I wrote this regex `^([a-zA-Z]*)+( {1})+([a-zA-Z]{1})+(\.)+([a-zA-Z]{1})+(\.)`, but it doesn't seem to work properly (the expression still allows n number of spaces, for example). How do I restrict it? `{1}` doesn't work.

Comment: take a look at what `+` does and then re-evaluate at which parts in your regex you really need it. Also `.` is a metacharacter and needs to be escaped.

Comment: also `{1}` is doing nothing since the default is a single occurrence - and then followed by `+`?? e.g. `"  "` is exactly one space, `" [a-zA-Z]"`  is exactly one space followed by exactly one letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
^([a-zA-Z])+([ ]{1})([a-zA-Z]{1})([.])([a-zA-Z]{1})([.])
```

I've taken space and dots into class (`[]`). If you don't do this with dot, then it means any character. Alo pluses are redundant, they mean more than one character.

P.S.: @f1sh correctly notices, that having `{1}` doesn't change a thing, so the shorter form would be:

```
^([a-zA-Z])+([ ])([a-zA-Z])([.])([a-zA-Z])([.])
```

Comment: @f1sh you're right I've noticed on clicking "answer":) corrected

Comment: now it's correct :) Even though using `{1}` is redundant and can be removed.

Comment: are you being paid per character? `([  ])` why choose one letter from only "space" and as capturing group? Why `([.])` and not just `\\.`?

Comment: @f1sh again agreed, added your suggestion;)

Comment: Also the groups can probably be removed: `^[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z][.][a-zA-Z][.]` or even `^[a-zA-Z]+ ([a-zA-Z][.]){2}`

Comment: Or a bit shorter `^[a-zA-Z]+ ([a-zA-Z]\.){2}`

Comment: I didn't remove the groups, because I didn't know, if they wouldn't be used later on.